# trouble using juggernaut as a rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, juggernaut

i am developing a rails plugin, in which i want a model where server will notify updates to all the connected clients. for simplicity say, on certain event server will say 'hi there is an update' to all the clients.

i came across juggernaut plugin that uses web-sockets and have followed https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut_plugin/tree/c3e07a812341f93bb1f90c00b7a125524b07b80a

but its not working for me.

can any one help me figuring out what am i missing, simply to send an alerts to the clients.

or is there some simpler library or simpler way to get on with it?

any suggestions/comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about Faye? Here's a Railscasts [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)

Comment: i looked at faye, but couldnt find enough documentation, examples.. new users may face some difficulty in using the library.

Comment: I think the screencast is valuable, I think juggernaut is powerful too, but I faced some problems when I last used juggernaut last year and the documentation was poor too, I think the screencast is enough

Answer (score 1):

juggernaut_plugin hasn't been updated for three years. You want [Juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut), the much more recently and recently-updated version. Try following the instructions for that.