# How to use Comet in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, comet

Is there any library to use Comet in Rails 3?

I read that Juggernaut does not work anymore.

I'm using Passenger standalone as the server.

Comment: I don't know, somewhere. Does it work?

Comment: @mu-is-too-short Thanks! It was worth the installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried Juggernaut and had some problems installing its dependencies, but after solving that it worked just fine. It does not depend on Rails, you only need Ruby, so it works with Rails 3 too.

Answer (score 2):

What about [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/)? Here's a Railscast [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) which will help you.

By the way, we discussed this issue a few days ago. Here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432285/trouble-using-juggernaut-as-a-rails-plugin/9434592#9434592).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I will try it if juggernaut ever fails me. But for now, I already have a working comet server (juggernaut). I made it work yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pusher](http://pusher.com/). It's not free, but very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Juggernaut does not work anymore due [SSEs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/).

This is a browser API that lets you keep open a socket to your server, subscribing to a stream of updates. It's perfect for the use-case Juggernaut was created for, and what's more can be implemented in a few lines of Ruby. In other words, it makes Juggernaut completely redundant.

I found a gem that implements some Comet functionalities: [Cramp](http://cramp.in/), I haven't used it yet, but you can try to implement it in your proyect.